# WordPress posts will not show consistently

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to load posts from only a specific category on each page template. Once I got it working on one page template (category ID 9), I am using the same code on other page templates (cat Ids 12, 13, 14, etc). It will only work on the first one I created though. Why would this not work on whichever page template I place this code and subsequent category ID's?

```
      <?php 
        $args = array(
          'posts_per_page' => 10,
          'category__in' => array( 9 ),
        );

        $project = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $project->have_posts() ):
          while( $project->have_posts() ):
            $project->the_post();
      ?>
```

Comment: Additional context, all single-digit categories work using the code above. Almost like it's a double-digit thing, which I know is ridiculous.

Comment: I've figured out I'm not handling them in my functions.php properly.  Here is what I have, which will only show the last category from the list.
'
function wpse_category_set_post_types( $query ){
if( $query->is_category ):
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'lega_resource' ) );
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'lgbtq_resources' ) );
endif;
return $query;
}